# error setting certificate verify locations - PayPal IPN Listener

Tags: php, mysql, curl, paypal

Hi I am quite new to coding and trying my best to get out of my noob status
I got myself started with apache 2.4, mysql, php 5.6 on Windows 7
(I guess people call this WAMP, but it was only yesterday that I learned the existence of WAMP)

Anyways,
I am currently working on my own website that will eventually lead to payment by a user. Using, paypal, upon payment (the checkoutpage.php is set and has no problems), I need to update my mysql database. So, for past 10 days, I have been working on the ipn_listener.php file and now I understand the basic flow of this(I think).

However I keep getting this error as below.
  error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:absolute\path\to\cacert.pem
  CApath: none

and this is driving me CRAZY
And I HAVE googled for more than a week now but still have not been able to solve this problem.
I know I am missing something but Ive tried so many things like..
installing ngrok (still doing this)
installing openssl 1.0.1l
installing curl (php supports this. checked from phpinfo())

Here is the listener script that I've come up with so far

```
<?php

  require_once('appvars.php');
  require_once('connectvars.php');

  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);

// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);


define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");


// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data

if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}

$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}

// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.

$cert = dirname(__FILE__) . "\cert\cacert.pem";
//$cert = "C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\PEM\cacert.pem";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;

} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}

// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.

    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $payerid = $_POST['payer_id']; //this is id for PAYPAL

    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $payeremail = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $paymentdate = $_POST['payment_date'];
    $paymentstatus = $_POST['payment_status']; 
    $mdate= date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($paymentdate));
    $otherstuff = json_encode($_POST);

     //And THEN I DO THINGS HERE (but this fails everytime
     //because of the said error)


    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Check that you have a file of certificate at the specified path, for the beginning

Comment: Also you may try to comment out `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert)`, and try disabling verify peer, as pointed in the answer below. But beware, this reduces security, namely allows simeone to pretend he is paypal.

Comment: @dmitry Ive made sure that it is there

Comment: and also I know that switching it off is one of the solutions but its not the real solution that Im looking for

Answer (score 2):

It seems the verification of certificate failed. You can bypass the verification by changing CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0).